# Zend Framework - Ruby on Rails has a screencast showing how to code a blog in 15 minutes. Does ZF have a similar screencast?

Tags: zend-framework, rad

Ruby on Rails has a screencast presentation they use to promote their framework that [shows how to code a basic weblog system in 15 minutes with RoR](http://rubyonrails.org/screencasts). **Does the Zend PHP Framework have a similar screencast/presentation/whatever demonstrating something similar?** It doesn't have to be a blog specifically, but I would definitely like to find a presentation that shows some rapid application development using ZF.

**Where I'm coming from:** I have been programming on and off for years now. I started out with QBASIC *waaaaay* back in the day making little programs (text adventure games, screensavers, simple little things). I then moved to C++ but never really did anything too impressive with it. Since then (probably 5 years or so now) I have started to use C# for my desktop development and PHP for my web development. I've made some pretty cool tools here and there, but am certainly not a professional programmer by any stretch of the term as it has always simply been a hobby of mine.

Right now I have two major web applications that I will start work on shortly. (Like tomorrow, or later *tonight* ideally.. :) ) Both will be database-driven apps that will require user registration, the ability to manipulate data that is specific to their account (their posts, listings, user account details, etc), amongst other things.

Currently I am evaluating different frameworks to help me develop these web apps more quickly. I've been looking at, and have heard good things about Ruby on Rails. Hulu and YellowPages.com using it is an obvious endorsement - Of course, I have heard about the scalability issues that it potentially has; but that shouldn't be an issue with what I am working on. I don't expect millions of users per day for either project.

I am also seriously looking at the Zend Framework for my needs because I already have some experience with PHP. Ideally I would like to find a ZF screencast that shows an app being written quickly so that I have a roughly equal comparison between the two options I am exploring and can see first-hand how things get done in both.

That said - I am not opposed to considering frameworks other than RoR or ZF. The only research I've done on the subject has been over the past couple of days so I am quite certain that there are other excellent options out there that I've not even looked at - or heard of. Of course, it'd be awesome if there is a rapid app dev presentation that I can watch for whatever else is suggested.

So - **Suggestions?** Links to good screencasts that show rapid application development in other frameworks? Are there other PHP frameworks that I should be considering? (Ones that are easy to deploy would be ideal, so I don't have to purchase a dedicated server that I have full control over. I'd like to keep my hosting costs down assuming that it's reasonable)

Thanks in advance!

**-Sootah**

Comment: Alrighty, in addition to ZF and RoR I have found CodeIgniter and CakePHP. CodeIgniter catches my eye right off the bat because they claim, at least on the homepage, that it doesn't require command line access. It'd be nice to have a framework I can just access as an include or whatnot.

So - Thoughts on CodeIgniter or CakePHP? Additionally, I found a "create a blog in 20 minutes" video for CI.

Thanks again!

-Sootah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout [ZendCasts.com](http://www.zendcasts.com/)

However, when deciding between ZF and RoR, you should be aware that they are very different from each other. RoR is a full stack with integrated ORM built on AR and a rather rigid structure. It's powerful and there is lots of magic inside and I'd say it's RAD capabilities are above ZF due to rake being more powerful than Zend_Tool

ZF, on the other hand, is first and foremost a loosely coupled component library with a use-at-will architecture for maximum flexibility. You can use it's components together, but you don't have to. While it does feature convention over configuration, ZF doesn't take you by the hand too much. It expects you know how to walk. Also ZF has no full fledged ORM and no AR, but you can very much integrate Doctrine or Propel or whatever library you like to use.

You often hear folks new to ZF complain about it is hard to get into it, simply because they expect ZF to work like RoR or Symfony or Cake, e.g. a [full stack framework](http://phpframeworks.com/)

**EDIT**:

Cake aims to be a port of RoR to PHP. It is built around ActiveRecord. Like CI < v2, it is backwards compatible with PHP4, which means it doesn't fully utilize the OOP capabilities you get in PHP5. I'd say both are easier to get in than ZF though.

Comment: According to the research I've done on the subject so far, I'd have to agree with you both. I came across a few other PHP MVC frameworks, and so far CodeIgniter looks to be the best suited for me.

It doesn't require constant command-line access, nothing special has to be installed on the server running it (you just upload the framework to the root of whatever your developing), and they appear to have some excellent documentation, videos, and tutorials on how to get started with it.

Comment: @Sootah ZF doesn't require constant command line access either. You don't have to use Zend_Tool to get coding. It's just a convenience  tool for RAD, like RoR's rake or Cake's bake. Also, ZF doesn't require you to install something on the server either. But pick whatever suits you. If it's CI, perfect.

Comment: ZF is far less invasive then other FW. You yust upload the "Zend" folder anywhere in your include path. It can be server-wide or inside your document root. CI you mentioned will "poison" the whole application directory.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common question on SO.

I posted some valuable links in [my response to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347626/any-good-reference-zend-framework-based-applications-for-beginners/2347795#2347795)

If you Google for such tutorials, look for Zend Application or Zend Tool, not ZF.

The difference between the other frameworks and Zend Framework is that Zend Framework is rather a general purpose framework, not application framework (not only for MVC, HTTP). E.g. Google uses ZF to provide access to their services.

You may easily use Symfony or CodeIgnitier with Zend Framework together.

BTW, To be precise, tutorials you ask are not blogs, but just a simple CRUD controllers. You may use Wordpress to create blog in 15 minutes, (then customize it) but not a PHP Framework.

Comment: The apps I'm looking to develop aren't blogs at all. I was just hoping that there were rapid development videos on how to create a blog (albeit an extremely simple one) for each framework though, in order to have a 1 to 1 comparison between the languages.

A video showing something else being developed quickly would also be useful, but not quite as much simply because they would be implementing different features in the examples.

Thanks for your input!